# How to kill process in robotframework

Tags: python, process, robotframework

i am trying to kill process in robot framework, although the log says that process is killed , i am still able to see the command prompt invoked by the process Library.

is there anyway to kill the invoked command prompt in Suite Teardown ?

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process
Suite Setup    Generic Suite Setup
Suite TearDown    Terminate All Processes    kill=True
*** Test Cases ***
login
*** Keywords ***
Generic Suite Setup
    #This is invoking cmd 

    #when i run this , got error as mentioned below 
    Run Process    appium    -p     4723

    Run Process    appium    -p     4750

    #I tried to include cmd , no error but can't see the cmd getting invoked 
    Run Process    cmd    appium    -p     4750
```

My python version :2.7.14
pybot version : 3.0.2

After removing **start** & **"cmd"**  i get the error

Parent suite setup failed:
**WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

Appium path is set in environment variables

Comment: Did you start those process via the `Process Library`?

Comment: Yes, I am using Process library.

Comment: Right, sorry. I miss understood what your code was doing. Have you tried the keyword `Terminate Process`? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Terminate%20Process - It seems that you have, under the `Terminate All Processes`, can you show us that?

Comment: sorry i did n't understand your question? i have used Terminate process , it did n't worked.

Comment: Is the above code, your complete code which you can show us? If there is more code, please show me.

Comment: yes that's the complete code . Expectation ==>  1) in Generic Suite Setup , i want to invoke "cmd"  2) Suite Teardown , i want to close the "cmd"

Comment: What do you mean by "see the command prompt"? Do you mean that a window pops up with the command prompt?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley ..yes  i am invoking a window command prompt , and pushing command "appium -P 4723" and "appium -P 4750" ...in Suite Tear down i want these cmd windows to close down .

Comment: Why are you starting cmd and having cmd start appium? Why not just directly start appium?

Comment: @BryanOakley i edited my code, however i am still not able to close invoked "cmd"

Comment: You probably don't need to use `start`. At least part of the problem is likely that that you're starting a process (cmd) that starts a process (start) that starts a process (appium). And since you use `shell=True`, it's probably starting a shell process before starting all of those other processes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158163/discussion-between-pankaj-mishra-and-bryan-oakley).

Comment: @Bryan Oakley ..can you suggest how can i invoke a terminal or cmd (os indepenedent) , run the command "appium -p 4723 " on it and then terminate the terminal or cmd after use.

Comment: Have you tried doing as I suggested, and removing the `start` and `shell=True` parts?

Comment: @BryanOakley  see my edits

Comment: You need to read the documentation more closely. Every argument to appium needs to be a separate argument in robot `run process` `appium`, `-p`, `4723`

Comment: @bryanOakley  see the edits

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Start Process`, each argument that you would use on a command line needs to be an argument in robot. For example, if you would type `appium -p 4723` on the command line, then in robot you would do:

```
Start process  appium  -p  4723
```

(note: there are two spaces between "process", "appium", "-p", and "4723")

When you do this, robot will look through the folders in your PATH environment variable in order to find a program named "appium" (or "appium.exe" on windows). If you get the error "cannot find the file specified" that usually means that the program you're trying to run isn't in a folder in your PATH. It could also mean that the program isn't installed, or that you misspelled the app name, but I'm assuming neither of those are true in this case.

The simplest solution is to find where the appium executable is, and then use the full and complete path as the first argument to `Run Process` (eg: `Run Process  C:/the/path/to/appium.exe  -p  4723`)